# System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List<Territory> to List<UserTerritory>

Tags: query, list, map, database, set

I have below code that throws exception as mentioned in subject.

**Error**

```
System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List<Territory> to List<UserTerritory>
```

**Apex class code**

```
results = Database.query('SELECT id FROM user where salesforce_abt__c  in : Splitlist');
resultIds = (new Map<Id,user>(results)).keySet(); // This is a set of ids
    userterrs = Database.query('select id from territory where id in (select territoryid from userterritory where userid in : resultids)');  .// This line throws error. userterrs is a list of Territory object
    userterrsIds = (new Map<Id,territory>(userterrs)).keySet();  // This is a set of ids
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserTerrs` must be a `List<UserTerritory>`. If it were a `List<Territory>`, your assignment would go through without a hitch. Make sure you're assigning to the correct variable, and also make sure you have not "[shadowed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_name_shadowing.htm)" your variable with a local name.